# HTML instead of XAML in ASP?

Tags: html, visual-studio, xaml

I just started a new job and have never done web development before.  But i am looking at their products and it looks like on the front end they are grabbing html that their UI designers give them and posting in front end.  Visual studio complains about this, and i think this is affecting VS from seeing controls sometimes.  Is there also performance issues this can cause by not using XAML? Is there any arguments i can use to get the UI designer to be giving us XAML instead of HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like i just needed this in my beginning html tag `<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">`

Answer (score 0):

Team Foundation Server

This product is designed to fix this. It allows the UI designers to be all creative in any way they want, while automatically compiling the UI into functional XAML for the developers.

Comment: TFS is a pretty expensive solution.

Comment: @Chris: True, but I'm assuming this is a professional development context. TFS is the generally expected (and accepted) level of support for this industry, and most companies who can afford their own developers can afford TFS.